# SQL Server Management Studio concatenate multiple rows using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server

I'm having again a bit of trouble implementing the XML PATH method of concatenating multiple rows.

Given the following SQL Server `temptable`:

```
project    |    NAME    |      display_name
-----------+------------+-------------------
  a         Developer         Amelia     
  a         Developer         Ruby
  a         Administrator     Olivia     
  b         User              Isla    
  b         Developer         Emily   
  c         User              Poppy     
  c         Administrator     Ava    
  c         Administrator     James
```

The result should be:

```
project    |    NAME        | display_name
-----------+----------------+----------------
  a         Developer         Amelia, Ruby
            Administrator     Olivia

  b         User              Isla    
            Developer         Emily   

  c         User              Poppy     
            Administrator     Ava,James
```

Is something like this even possible with XML PATH etc. ?

Comment: Your query is a simple case of the usual solution. Could you post it to see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `FOR XML PATH()` clause :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.project, t.name, STUFF(t1.display_name, 1, 1, '') AS display_name
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ', '+t1.display_name 
      FROM table t1
      WHERE t1.project = t.project AND t1.name = t.name
      FOR XML PATH('')
     ) t1(display_name);
```

Comment: I like your sintaxis of calling the subquery on a cross apply and removing the trailing , on the result. Much cleaner, I will use it.